# MongoDB cursor.each method returns a final null value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var cursor = db.collection('Carreer').find();
cursor.each(function (err, results) {
    // the last results call is null
});
```

This loop seems to run one extra time, returning `null` as the last value for every column in the table. 
How do I stop `cursor.each` from returning the `null` value?

Comment: Try toArray and check log, how many array elements are there, db.collection('Carreer').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log(result)
  })

Comment: are you using mongoshell or node ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of [`cursor.each`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#each). The `null` value indicates there are no more results (ie the cursor is exhausted/empty and closed). If you don't want the extra `null` call when the cursor is finished, you can use [`cursor.forEach`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach):

```
db.collection('Carreer').find().forEach(function(doc) {
  // handle
}, function(err) {
  // done or error
});
```

Also note:

> [`cursor.each` is deprecated](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#each).

**Why the `null`?**

The `cursor.each` method just has [one callback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#~resultCallback) and the only way to know the cursor has finished is the last `null`. An example implementation could be:

```
function fetchAllCareers(callback) {
    const results = [];
    const cursor = db.collection('Carreer').find();
    cursor.each(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
            return;
        }
        if (result === null) { // This was the last iteration, we finished
            callback(null, results);
            return;
        }
        results.push(result);
    });
}
```

The `cursor.forEach` method on the other hand has an an [iterator callback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#~iteratorCallback) and a [second callback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#~endCallback) to let you know that the iterations have finished. An example implementation could be:

```
function fetchAllCareers(callback) {
    const results = [];
    const cursor = db.collection('Carreer').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(result) {
        results.push(result);
    }, function(error) { // all iterations finished
        callback(error, results);
    });
}
```

Comment: @PrajvalM, it is correct. see http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach

Comment: Yea it worked... I dont understand why forEach End At last data while each keep running one time extra any logical explanation to this..

Comment: They just work differently, `cursor.each` just has one callback and the final `null` lets you know the iterations have finished and you can do your final logic when you receive the `null`. `cursor.forEach` on the other hand, has an iterator callback and a second finish callback which lets you know the iterations have finished.